# Rsync command fails in Cygwin

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cygwin, rsync

I've been struggling with this for a day now and can't figure out what I'm doing, I haven't been able to find anything with Google some hopefully someone here can help:
I'm trying to use rsync to sync a folder between my Ubuntu server and my window's machine using Cygwin.  I issue:

`$ rsync -av -e "ssh 10.0.0.28 -pxxxx -i /home/my_user/.ssh/id_rsa -l my_user" my_user@10.0.0.28:/backup/folder/ /backup/folder/
bash: 10.0.0.28: command not found
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [Receiver=3.1.1]`

If I just extract the code in the double quotes and run it it correctly opens the ssh connection.  Does anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should not specify an address and login in ssh command. Rsync will do it for you. Try

```
rsync -av -e "ssh -pxxxx -i /home/my_user/.ssh/id_rsa" my_user@10.0.0.28:/backup/folder/ /backup/folder
```